# Why is a kubernetes pod with a simple hello-world image getting a CrashLoopBackOff message

Tags: kubernetes

`pod.yml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: hello-pod
    labels:
        zone: prod
        version: v1
spec:
    containers:
    - name: hello-ctr
      image: hello-world:latest
      ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
```

`kubectl create -f pod.yml`

```
kubectl get pods
NAME        READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
hello-pod   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   5          5m
```

Why `CrashLoopBackOff`?

Comment: can be a lot a reason. Maybe the node can't pull it due to a network flux closed for example. Check events with `kubectl get events` to obtain more information

Comment: @Snowcrash if my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case the expected behavior is correct. The hello-world container is meant to print some messages and then exit after completion. So this is why you are getting `CrashLoopBackOff` -

Kubernetes runs a pod - the container inside runs the expected commands and then exits.

Suddenly there is nothing running underneath - so the pod is ran again -> same thing happens and the number of `restarts` grows.

You can see that in`kubectl describe pod` where `Terminated` state is visible and the `Reason` for it is status `Completed`. If you would choose a container image which does not exit after completion the pod would be in running state.

Answer (score 3):

The `hello-world` is actually exiting meaning Kubernetes thinks its crashing, and keeps restarting and exiting and going in `CrashLoppBackOff`. When you `docker run` your `hello-world` container you get this:

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
$
```

So, it's a one-time thing and not a service. Kubernetes has [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) or [CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/) for these types of workloads.