# How to redirtect terminal STDIN when running a script in Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, sh, tty

I have a script that consumes users input. It is run like this:

```
./script <<EOF
> input
> onther input
> more input
> EOF
```

I need to distribute the script as a Docker image.

I am able to run the script in two steps.
First, I get into the containers shell.

```
docker run -it my-docker-tag sh
```

And then, inside the shell, I execute the script itself.

**Question:** Is it possible to run the script in on shut (without having to navigate to the containers shall)?

I tried this:

```
docker run -it my-docker-tag ./script <<EOF
> input
> onther input
> more input
> EOF
```

But it fails with:

> the input device is not a TTY

Comment: -i will try and assign a tty and so use -d instead.

Comment: @RamanSailopal could you please elaborate?

Comment: "Not a tty" refers to the `-t` option; does removing `-t`, or both `-i` and `-t`, make it better?

Comment: @DavidMaze removing "t" helped. Please posy it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Docker run reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891053/why-is-a-kubernetes-pod-with-a-simple-hello-world-image-getting-a-crashloopbacko) notes:

> Specifying `-t` is forbidden when the client is receiving its standard input from a pipe, as in:
>
> ```sh
> $ echo test | docker run -i busybox cat
> ```

If you remove the `-t` option, shell pipes and redirections around a (foreground) `docker run` command will work as you expect.

```sh
# A heredoc as in the question should work too
sudo docker run --rm my-docker-tag ./script <script-input.txt
```